# How Do I Import From 'com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.*' For Custom PicturesService for Gluon Mobile

Tags: android, javafx, gluon-mobile

I did not like how gluon `PicturesService` only gives you a javafx Image object when taking a picture or choosing from the phone's gallery, so after a lot of searching I ended up making a `FilePicturesService` by tweaking the source code. Instead, this service return a byte array for the image's JPEG file.

This worked out fine for the IOS native code. I built my own FPictures.h and FPicture.m files and copied the IOSPicturesService code into my project to create my own custom service. Tutorial used to create custom services is [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative/).

I thought that the android portion of this service would be the easy part. With the service interface already defined for the IOS code all I had to do was copy the **AndroidPicturesService.java** into my **AndroidFilePicturesService.java** and adjust the class name and return types. However when I tried to do this I got this error:

`package com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android does not exist`

Below are the two import statements that are effected by this.

**AndroidFilePicturesService.java**

```
package com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android;

...

import com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.FileUtils;
import com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.PermissionRequestActivity;

...

public class AndroidFilePicturesService implements FilePicturesService {

    ...

    @Override
    public Optional<byte[]> takePhoto(boolean savePhoto) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.multiplatformgluonapplication" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <application android:label="MultiplatformGluonApplication" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="MultiplatformGluonApplication" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                    <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.multiplatformgluonapplication.MultiplatformGluonApplication"/>
                    <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.PermissionRequestActivity" />
    </application>
```

How can I resolve this error? I am not sure where to even begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a custom service, but you are still relying on the Charm Down core classes, you need them to build it.

You have to use the `com.gluonhq.charm.down` package, so you can use the `Services` and `ServiceFactory` classes from the Charm Down `core` package.

As for the `PermissionRequestActivity` class this is part of the core-Android [package](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/11c36e187921b2eac4a3d518cc00ad9108cab89f/plugins/core/android/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/impl/charm/down/plugins/android/PermissionRequestActivity.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

In your project you can just add this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    androidCompile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-core-android:3.7.0'
}
```

As for the `FileUtils` class, this is part of the PicturesService Android [implementation](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/11c36e187921b2eac4a3d518cc00ad9108cab89f/plugins/plugin-pictures/android/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/impl/charm/down/plugins/android/FileUtils.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

If you are doing your own implementation of this service, you either copy this class to your project, or you add it as dependency:

```
dependencies {
    androidCompile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-core-android:3.7.0'
    androidCompile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-pictures-android:3.7.0'
}
```